# Can each polynomial of degree $k+1$ be expressed as $(x-c)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is one degree less?

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, field-theory

Can each polynomial of degree $k+1$ be expressed as $(x-c)g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is one degree less? Over the complex field, say. If not, what about over the reals?

Comment: Yes, and no. (Consider $1+x^2$ over the reals.)

Answer (score 0):

If possible such a $c$ would be called a root of the polynomial $f(x)$. Now it is a question of whether you want the roots to be in the same field or an extension field. For complex filed the fundamental theorem of algebra states that a factorization of $f(x)$ is possible into degree 1 factors (with possible repetitions).